# combine every item in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm breaking my brains for a couple of days now and I hope someone can point me to the right direction to achieve this.

I have an array like this:

```
Array (
    [Option A] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value 1
            [1] => Value 2
        )

    [Option B] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value 1
            [1] => Value 2
        )
)
```

I need to combine the options so it results in a list like this.

```
Option A : Value 1, Option B Value 1
Option A : Value 1, Option B Value 2
Option A : Value 2, Option B Value 1
Option A : Value 2, Option B Value 2
```

Comment: 2 loops! One inside the other !! Show us what you have coded so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 2 loops one inside the other like this

```
foreach ($arr['OptionA'] as $a) {
    foreach ($arr['OptionB'] as $b) {
        echo sprintf('Option A : %s, Option B : %s', $a, $b);
    }
}
```

Comment: it couldn't be that simple. I'm sure I've tried this. Maybe had a typo or something wrong in the second loop.
I've tried so many things but this works.